# Menu bar for solitaire in pygame

Tags: python, menu, pygame

I am trying to make a menu bar for a Solitaire in Pygame. I know how to do it in botn wxpython and Tkinter but I can´t find any info about how to do it in pygame. I want to be able to create a new game, undo and quit. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default "menu bar" option in Pygame. You will have to code it yourself. I would recommend making a separate class called something like `Menu_Bar` which has methods like `__init__` and `draw` and variables like "buttons" or in your case, "New Game", "Undo", and "Quit".

Then in the main loop of your pygame game, you will have to use the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` along with the `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and check if the user clicked on any of the `Rect`s of the `Menu_Bar` class and then execute the required code.

I'd recommend you check this out:
http://nebelprog.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/create-a-simple-game-menu-with-pygame-pt-1-writing-the-menu-options-to-the-screen/

and also other similar sites online that have a walkthrough of how to make a [Menu in Pygame](https://www.google.com/search?q=menu%20in%20pygame&rlz=1C1CHMR_enMY529MY529&oq=menu%20in%20pygame&aqs=chrome..69i57.2102j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)